# эффект, если пользователь находится на определённой странице

Tags: php, javascript, css

```css
.item {
    font-family: calibri;
    color: #b1b1b1;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <a class="item" href="index.php">Главная</a>
    <a class="item" href="popular-page.php">Популярное</a>
    <a class="item" href="catalog-page.php">Каталог</a>
    <a class="item" href="sale-page.php">Скидки</a>
    <a class="item" href="video-page.php">Видео</a>
    <a class="item" href="contact-page.php">Контакты</a>
</nav>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такое меню, надо чтобы было так, если пользователь находится на странице home.php т.е главной, то элемент li принимал свой-во color: #fff; А если на popular.php то "популярно" и т.д

Comment: Вместо картинки выложите лучше html. Иначе ответ будет до абсурда  банален.

Comment: Не только html, но и попытку решения.

Comment: @Arnial готово.

Comment: читаем про window.location: 
проверяем наше местоположение, создаем if'ы и используем какой-нибудь класс актив, который будет подсвечивать в меню необходимую точку прибывания.
А вообще лучше бэкэндом это делать.

Answer (score 1):

Доброе всем утро.
Один из вариантов, как можно сделать.
1. В начале каждой страницы вводим элемент с атрибутом:

```
 <div id="currentpage" data-currentpage="catalog"></div>
```

Там где написано `catalog`, на каждой странице прописываете соответствующую метку.
2. Чуть изменяем меню:

```
<nav id="navigation">
...
<a class="item" id="catalog" href="catalog-page.php">Каталог</a>
<a class="item" id="video" href="video-page.php">Видео</a>
...
```

3. Пишем небольшой jQuery:

```
(function(w){
   var  attribute = $('#currentpage').attr('data-currentpage');

   $('#' + attribute).addClass('select');
})(this);
```

Повторюсь, это один из возможных вариантов.